# Data not loading into my Spinner

Tags: android, components

I'm trying to load an array of data into a Spinner component and it's throwing a NullPointerException. The code I'm using is below and it all seems okay.

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<?> spin_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.letters_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spin_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spin_adapter);
```

The string-array looks like this

```
<string-array name="letters_array">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
    <item>C</item>
    <item>D</item>
    <item>E</item>
    <item>F</item>
    <item>G</item>
    <item>H</item>
    <item>I</item>
    <item>J</item>
    <item>K</item>
    <item>L</item>
    <item>M</item>
    <item>N</item>
    <item>O</item>
    <item>P</item>
    <item>Q</item>
    <item>R</item>
    <item>S</item>
    <item>T</item>
    <item>U</item>
    <item>V</item>
    <item>W</item>
    <item>X</item>
    <item>Y</item>
    <item>Z</item>
</string-array>
```

Is there a limit to the number of items in a Spinner or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Where does the NullPointerException occur? Could you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: @User616076: I got the data into the spinner using above code .No Problem in that code

Comment: add more code....NPE might be @ R.id.spinner, if you are inflating the layout....
or add your exception stack trace.....

Comment: Yes you are right the code is ok, the problem is (and I appologise for not mentioning this earlier) that the spinner is set in an AlertDialog that runs of of this activity. When I set up a spinner in the main activity the code works fine. What I need to work out now is that is it possible to have a spinner in an AlertDialog and if so how do I tell my code that the spinner is in my dialoglayout.xml and not my mainactivity.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> spin_adapter = ...
```

In which xml-File is your Array stored and where is it located?

Comment: The array is stored in my strings.xml but the problem seems to be that my spinner is stored in my dialoglayout.xml as it is supposed to be in an AlertDialog. I'm not sure how to configure my code so that it knows that the spinner is in my dialoglayout.xml and not my mainactivity.xml.